# What are different between android.intent.category.DEFAULT and android.intent.category.PREFERENCE?

Tags: android

I use  `openActivity<MyPreferenceActivity>()` to create a Preference UI in Android Studio 3.1.2 with Kotlin.

It seems that both Code A and Code B can work well.

What are different between `android.intent.category.DEFAULT` and `android.intent.category.PREFERENCE` ? Thanks!

**Code A**

```
<activity android:name="ui.MyPreferenceActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ui.MyPreferenceActivity" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

**Code B**

```
        <activity android:name="ui.MyPreferenceActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ui.MyPreferenceActivity" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.PREFERENCE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

**Both**

```
class MyPreferenceActivity : PreferenceActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(android.R.id.content, MyPreferenceFragment()).commit()
    }

    class MyPreferenceFragment : PreferenceFragment() {
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.aa)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of using an intent filter is for implicit intents. If your Activity is initiated by an implicit intent where no specific category is assigned to it, its Intent filter should include the category mentioned in the manifest file.

> It seems that both Code A and Code B can work well.

That is correct. The same code and functionality can be replicated by the an Activity "X" even by defining it as different intent activity filters and categories in the Manifest file. Like i've mentioned above, the purpose of an intent filter is in using implicit intent. If you defined it as a Preference Category intent in the manifest, Activity X would be called when you initiate an implicit intent of Preference type.

> What are different between android.intent.category.DEFAULT and android.intent.category.PREFERENCE

`android.intent.category.DEFAULT` is the default category for an implicit intent (AS in it does not have any specific role) whereas an activity defined as `android.intent.category.PREFERENCE` would be called when an implicit intent where you need to call a Preference Activity/Fragment/Panel.